# how to replace the values in column to a string when a condition is met

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to replace the values 0 or 1 in a column with 'hit' or 'flop'

```
select (Box_office_revenue-Budget)>Budget as hit_flop
from movie_data
hit_flop          hit_flop
    0               flop
    0               flop
    0               flop
    1               hit
    1               hit
```

how to replace the values with the texts without creating a new column

**Also, I want to get 'super hit' when box_office_revenue/budget > 10**

Answer (score 1):

```
select
Case when box_office_revenue/budget > 10 then 'Super Hit'
    when (Box_office_revenue-Budget)>Budget then 'Hit' 
    else 'Flop' end as hit_flop
from movie_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it is working, but now I needed a modification. I want to get 'super hit' when box_office_revenue/budget > 10, can you help me with that.

Comment: Case evaluates in order until a condition is true so it's just a matter of keeping the order of priority for the conditions. I've updated the answer.